# Subterfuge not starting

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am on the subterfuge local server and when I hit start it has a bar that says initiating but when that goes away nothing happens and it doesn't start.

When I hit start the Terminal says this

Starting Pwn Ops...
Running AutoPwn Method...
Using: eth0
Setting gateway as: 192.168.65.2
Automatically Configuring Subterfuge...
Iptables Prerouting Configured
Configuring System...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
IP Forwarding Enabled.
Initiating ARP Poison With ARPMITM...
Poisoning: Network
Starting up SSLstrip...
[23/Mar/2016 18:51:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 71939
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Harvesting Credentials...
Starting FTP Sniffer
Poisoning the entire subnet...
[23/Mar/2016 18:51:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 71939
sslstrip 0.9 by Moxie Marlinspike running...

And then it has lines popping up every couple seconds

How do I get it to start

Answer (score 0):

Check out, if it is running in the background:

```
ps aux | grep -e 'subterfuge' | grep -v 'grep'
```

Or try to start it as root from terminal:

```
sudo subterfuge
```

Comment: I did run it from terminal as root and it is running in the terminal... Or at least I think it is because lines keep popping up

Comment: What do I do. Somebody help